# Cloud storage rewrite not resetting the componentsCount property

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm composing several files into one and then i do perform a "rewrite" operation to reset componentsCount, so they won't block further compositions (to avoid 1024 components problem, actually). But, the resulting rewritten object's componentCount property increases as if it was just a "rename" request.

It is stated in documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite):

> When you rewrite a composite object where the source and destination
>   are different locations and/or storage classes, the result will be a
>   composite object containing a single component (and, as always with
>   composite objects, it will have only a crc32c checksum, not an MD5).

It is not clear to me what do they mean by "different locations" -- different object names and/or different buckets?

Is there a way to reset this count w/o downloading and uploading resulting composite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations refers to geographically where the source and destination bucket are (us-east1, asia, etc.) -- see https://cloud.google.com/about/locations

If your rewrite request is between buckets in different locations and/or storage classes, the operation does byte copying and (in the case of composite objects) will result in a new object with component count 1. Otherwise the operation will complete without byte copying and in that case (in the case of composite objects) will not change the component count.

Comment: So, there is no way to reset componentCount within one bucket and location internally inside cloud storage?

Comment: Not without copying to another bucket or downloading/re-uploading.

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer necessary to reset the component count using rewrite or download/upload because there's no longer a restriction on the component count. Composing > 1024 parts is allowed.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects